# Column "thickness" and "space usage" in column-chart in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

my column chart is not using all space available. The columns could be thicker, but when I change the pointWidth to a higher value, the columns get thicker, but instead of occupying more of the available white space, they just start to overlap.

[Here](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/soil_use_ch.php) is the chart.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- update Highcharts to latest version if possible (2.3.5)
- your series contains three points, [ value, value, NaN] - you probably have an extra end line "\n" in your CSV. Add checking if parseFloat isn't returning NaN (use isNaN() function).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, there was an empty line!

Answer (score 0):

If you change pointWidth you should also care about groupPadding / pointPadding which define space betweet points/groups.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.groupPadding